# Nonexistent function get_viewport in base Nil

Tags: syntax-error, viewport, screen-size, godot, gdscript

I am running a script:

```
func _ready():
    screensize.get_viewport().get_rect().size
    set_process(true)
    spawn_fruit(5)
```

I am getting an error: Nonexistent function get_viewport in base Nil
I've seen this error on other peoples scripts for get_rect and other functions, but nothing for this. I am new to GoDot so go easy on me please:)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution!
In Godot 3.1+ you can't use get_rect() because it was removed. You have to write it as:

```
screensize = get_viewport().size
```

Second of all, you have to use f.translate instead of f.set_pos:

```
f.set_pos(Vector2(rand_range(10, screensize.width-10), rand_range(10, screensize.height-10)))
```

```
f.translate(Vector2(rand_range(300, screensize.x-800),rand_range(300, screensize.y-800)))
```

Thirdly, Vector2 does not use .width and .height anymore. It was changed to .x and .y (Shown Above)

**Credit goes to LT Farms on YouTube**